# Basic device operations in spi driver

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, spi

I need to write an spi driver for omap4 from scratch.
I am referring http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c driver code.
But, I am unable to understand how basic device operations are handled in this driver code.
For example a char driver has the structure

```
struct file_operations scull_fops = {
.owner = THIS_MODULE,
.llseek = scull_llseek,
.read = scull_read,
.write = scull_write,
.ioctl = scull_ioctl,
.open = scull_open,
.release = scull_release,
};
```

containing the pointers to the basic functions like open, read, write etc...

I don't find these functions in 
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/spi/spi-omap2-mcspi.c

Somebody please help me identify how the device open, read & write are provided in the spi-omap2-mcspi.c code.

Comment: Did you try using a cross-reference tool?

Comment: There are two types of SPI drivers: master drivers and slave (or target) protocol drivers. `drivers/spi` is a directory for master drivers, i.e. for the SPI master controllers.  Are you writing a driver for the master or a slave device?

Comment: @sawdust Master driver

Comment: @lgnacio I use http://lxr.free-electrons.com

Comment: Have you read the [Linux/Documentation/spi/spi-summary](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/spi/spi-summary?a=arm) document?

Comment: @sawdust: yes, I've read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the bottom of the file you linked in your post, you will see the handling for the basic platform driver operations.

```
static const struct dev_pm_ops omap2_mcspi_pm_ops = {
        .resume = omap2_mcspi_resume,
        .runtime_resume = omap_mcspi_runtime_resume,
};

static struct platform_driver omap2_mcspi_driver = {
       .driver = {
                .name =         "omap2_mcspi",
                .owner =        THIS_MODULE,
                .pm =           &omap2_mcspi_pm_ops,
                .of_match_table = omap_mcspi_of_match,
       },
       .probe =        omap2_mcspi_probe,
       .remove =       omap2_mcspi_remove,
};
```

In the `probe` operation there you can see the setup of the spi specific operations for this driver:

```
     /* the spi->mode bits understood by this driver: */
     master->mode_bits = SPI_CPOL | SPI_CPHA | SPI_CS_HIGH;
     master->bits_per_word_mask = SPI_BPW_RANGE_MASK(4, 32);
     master->setup = omap2_mcspi_setup;
     master->auto_runtime_pm = true;
     master->transfer_one_message = omap2_mcspi_transfer_one_message;
     master->cleanup = omap2_mcspi_cleanup;
     master->dev.of_node = node;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer.But where are the open, read and write functions?

Comment: hnow i understand ;). I think a hint for this is in the /include/linux/spi/spi.h header. The controller driver needs a protocol driver which oes the real file operations. The fle operations are then mapped to the mentioned operations in the contrller driver.

Comment: Where is that protocol driver?
Do you know how the file operations are mapped to the mentioned operations?

Comment: It depens onwhich protocol you want to use on the SPI controller. The controller only handles sending and receiving bytes.

Comment: Getting closer :-)
Which operations in spi-omap2-mcspi.c handles sending and receiving bytes?

Comment: @SJMP - *"Where is that protocol driver?"*  -- The protocol driver is tailored for each SPI slave device.  But you claimed you wanted to write a master driver.  Maybe you need to study the SPI documentation again.

Comment: I would say omap2_mcspi_transfer_one_message(). Other operations seem to be generic and implemented in drivers/spi/spi.c

Comment: The offset addresses are registered in the #define section, but where is the base address for SPIx registered?